# How to run limited amount of instances of program?

Tags: cmd.exe, parallel-processing

For example, I have circa 14000 files I need to process
Right now I'm doing it with

```
for %%a in (*.OGG) do revorb.exe "%%a"
```

This runs all revorbs one after one. I have quad processor, so I'd like to run four instances of revorb at the same time, but not more than four.
I've tried

```
for %%a in (*.OGG) do start revorb.exe "%%a"
```

and it caused BSOD.
Is there another way to run four tasks in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this can't be done from the command line or batch program in Windows. This is because you can't control from the command line which core is assigned to a certain job. [You can only do this once an application is already running](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/change-the-processor-affinity-setting-in-windows-7-to-gain-a-performance-edge/). The "right" way to use different cores is by the application or program that does the (processor intensive) work. Applications use [multithreading](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(software)) to use different cores at the same time. Because multithreading makes code more complex, not all applications implement multithreading.

For audio/video encoding, multithreading really pays off. In your scenario, the "right" way to speedup is to use *all cores for each file* using multithreading instead of using *multiple threads/cores for instances of the program, encoding different files*.

The proper solution is to use an encoder which makes use of all of the cores *for each file it encodes*. For example [Libav](https://libav.org/avconv.html) or [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) would be suitable tools for this.

Comment: And just manually start the number of instances you want, and use some kind of file naming logic to control which files get processed by each instance without duplication?

Comment: There is no way to know how the OS (Windows) assigns the instances to the cores. Windows will not always assign each instance to a different core. You could start more processes than cores, hoping that Windows will eventually distribute them more or less evenly over the cores, but this results in a lot of task switching overhead. So in the end: having your application use all the cores while processing each file one by one makes the most optimal use of all cores.